# keyboard bug with onClickListener in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I have a problem with an editText. I want to put a default text in this editText and when you click on the text disappear and you can wirte a number. Every thing is going well with that code for the layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/yearEdit"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/chooseDate"
    android:textSize="13sp"
     />
```

and in the activity the edit text have as textWatcher and onClickListener :

```
private class ChooseYear implements TextWatcher, OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        if (!yearEdit.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            yearChoose = Integer.parseInt(yearEdit.getText()
                    .toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
            int arg2, int arg3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
            int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (yearChoose == -1) {
            yearEdit.setText("");
        }
    }

}
```

But my problem is : When i had it as the onClickListener, the android keyboard doesn't close anymore when i click on its "Done" button. Does someone know why ? Does it exist a proper way to fix it ?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Eliott

Comment: If you want to show some _default text_ in the `EditText` that should _disappear_ when clicked in, why not use `android:hint="@string/chooseDate"` instead of the current `android:text="@string/chooseDate"`? And I don't quite understand the rest of it. Is the only purpose of setting an `OnClickListener` to hide the keyboard?

Comment: I will try, android:hint="@string/chooseDate" to fix my case by removing the OnClickListener. But i am also interest about the fact than add an onClickListener deactivate the Done button of the keyboard so if anybody know about that, i am interest !

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but you might want to comment out the `onClickListener` when you are testing the hint attribute.

Comment: hint is not working in my case because i only have one editText and it is by default selected so the text never disappear, hint shall probably listen the onFocusedChanged. no ?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the OnClickListener? And if that is the only `EditText` and when your `Activity` starts if that is taking focus and hence not showing the hint, you can also try adding this attribute to your Activity in the manifest.xml: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`. This will not open the keyboard automatically and show the hint too.

Comment: the hint is shown the keyboard but it doesn't disappear when i click on the EditBox and start to wirte. Yes when i put hint, i disabling the OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are interest, this is my conclusion on my own problem.

It looks like the keyBoard doesn't work proprely (The "Done" button is not closing the keyboard) when you add an OnClickListener on the EditText. To solve the problem I have to add the line :

```
yearEdit.setOnClickListener(null);
```

in the code. When the OnClickListener is set to null, The "Done" button restart to work normally. You have to re-set the OnClickListener if you need it again after (not my case).

My opinion is that could be an Android bug, because there is no logic than an OnClickListener have an effect on the keyboard. If you want to share your opinion about it, i will be interest.